# "unauthorized: Unauthorized" message when pushing Docker container to Bluemix

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

Attempted to push my Docker container onto Bluemix with the command:

```
sudo docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/< my username>/testproj:latest
```

...but it remains in this state:

```
41e402a30e3e: Preparing 
31ea3086ff95: Preparing
7128d7a803a9: Preparing
03b6a8ac8cb2: Preparing 
3e76a9f5c51e: Preparing 
c747e356ef2e: Waiting 
5f2f91b41de9: Waiting 
ec0200a19d76: Waiting 
338cb8e0e9ed: Waiting 
d1c800db26c7: Waiting 
42755cf4ee95: Waiting 
unauthorized: Unauthorized
```

So the container doesn't push to Bluemix. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/237544/can-not-publish-my-container-to-bluemix.html

Comment: same problem here, in may case the problem turned out to be an extra forward slash in repo name. See https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/273695/error-while-executing-docker-push-command-access-t.html

Answer (score 1):

Before pushing image to bluemix, you can try out cf ic command to login, it might be possible that your login token become invalid, you can try:
**cf ic login** 
this will reset to valid token. 
Reference: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/205155/unable-to-add-docker-image-to-my-bluemix-registry.html

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to change anything, nor did anything else on that guide

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rahul's answer, make sure that you run the login as the same user as your `docker push` command. So, if you need to run your docker push with sudo, make sure to do your `cf login` and `cf ic login` with sudo as well.